# NUnit: abort test if it takes too long

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Is there a nice and simple way to get NUnit to kill a test that takes more than a specified amount of time?

Ideally it would not only kill the app domain in which the test was running, but also any child processes the test started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using NUnit 2.5 you can use the [Timeout](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5) attribute to fail the test after specified amount of time. Unfortunately you will need to clean all the resources yourself - e.g. in the TearDown method check if the processes are running and kill them etc.

Comment: No teardown will be executed if timeout in NUint3